# A more idiomatic way to get <div><div> with Symfony DOMCrawler

Tags: domcrawler

I have a `$brick` which is an instance of `Crawler` and this is how `$brick->html()` starts:

```
  <div>
          <div>testplain 1</div>
  </div>
```

I am fishing out the div containing `testplain 1` with:

```
  $content = $brick
    ->children()->first()
    ->children()->first();
```

but this is not nice. I know I could drop `first()` but that would make it even more confusing IMO. Is there a way to say first `<div>` of the first `<div>` in a nicer way with DOMCrawler?

Comment: If I remember properly you can use xpath in domcrowler. Can you do something like "//div[.//ancestor::div]" or $brick->filterXPath('//div/div')->html()

Comment: "A double slash " // " means any descendant node of the current node in the HTML tree which matches the locator." that certainly won't do. I am unsure whether `filterXpath('div/div')` would be anchored to the beginning or not.